# How to remove an import package dependency in python?

Tags: python-2.7, import, dependencies, package

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def main()
html_doc()=path.html
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(html_doc))
print soup
```

I want to remove this code dependency on beautiful soup . How can some other person which do not have BeautifulSoup installed on his machine run this code ?

Comment: Why not just install BeautifulSoup on that other computer too? It is a very specific and useful tool to parse HTML, if you don't want to use it you'll have to port your code to something else. You could use the standard library HTML parser but it is nowhere near as useful as what BeautifulSoup offers.

Answer (score 0):

> How can some other person which do not have BeautifulSoup installed on his machine run this code ?

All code that you pasted is centered on BeautifulSoup. Of course, someone who does not have that library won't be able to run your code. If you want to get rid of a function, you will have to implement its functionality in your own code. That's not a good idea, in most cases. In this case, try python's `urllib2`, which does HTTP fetching for you.